# Loading a class from a running java application (Remote or Local JVM)

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, classloader

I have been recently playing with the `Reflection API` and I have successfully shoot some calls such this one below, where I'm loading my class dynamically from a jar archive with the `URLClassLoader`:

```java
public class JarUrlClassLoader {

  public static void main(String args []){

    File jarFile = new File("PATH_TO_JAR_ARCHIVE.jar");
    String className = "org.test.MyClass";
    try
    {
      URL fileURL = jarFile.toURI().toURL();
      String jarURL = "jar:" + fileURL + "!/";
      URL urls [] = { new URL(jarURL) };
      URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
      Object obj = Class.forName(className, true, loader).newInstance();
      System.out.println("Object is: \"" + obj.toString() + "\"");
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InstantiationException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

This snippet works fine and seem simple to understand. However when I tried to go further assuming that this *jar file* was already under my **Tomcat AS** lib folder, which is by its turn up and listening to some port. This class `org.test.MyClass` may then be loaded into JVM and so I can load it from there instead of loading it from jar archive.
So I tried the below snippet which does not work:

```
public class RemoteUrlClassLoader {

  private static final String httpURL = "http://localhost:8080/";
  private static final String targetClass = "org.test.MyClass";

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Creating classloader for:" + httpURL);
    URL[] urls = {new URL(httpURL)};
    final ClassLoader newClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(newClassLoader);
    System.out.println("Loading: " + targetClass);
    Class urlClass = null;
    try {
      urlClass = newClassLoader.loadClass(targetClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Object obj = null;
    try {
      obj = urlClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Object is: \"" + obj.toString() + "\"");
  }
}
```

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to execute this snippet.
Actually I'm not surprised of such an exception but I do need some clarification whether I can or not do what I'm trying to fulfil: **load a class from a local or remote JVM (running application)**?
If yes, does this URL `httpURL = "http://localhost:8080/"` the statement I need to change or do I have to change the whole class?

BR.

Comment: You're basically asking if you can, via a URL, load a class that is completely outside of your control. This would let me do something like take all your app's bytecode--surely this would be the most epic security whole ever.

Comment: What about an application already running in local? such as I mentionned in my post?

Comment: Where the web app *lives* isn't relevant; the server will behave the same way. There is no direct access to your app's classes from the outside world, where "outside" means "not your web app". That would be disastrous. You could *expose* classes through your webapp itself.

Comment: I totally agree with you, so in such a case and assuming that I insist on such a functionality, does opening a socket channel to load classes through is a good idea?
Sorry but I don't got what you mean by `You could expose classes through your webapp itself.`?

Comment: Your app could load the class and stream it to the client. I don't understand what opening a socket channel has to do with anything; the issue is that the world outside your webapp doesn't, and shouldn't, have unfettered access to your app's classpath.

Comment: **Your app could load the class and stream it to the client**; could you more explain how can I do that please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47784/discussion-between-tmarwen-and-dave-newton)